# Is an enhancement bonus due to invested essentia sufficient to overcome DR X/magic?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, natural-weapon, meldshaping

*Magic of Incarnum* describes several soulmelds that when shaped or bound grant the meldshaper one or more natural weapons. When a meldshaper invests essentia into some of these soulmelds, these natural weapons gain enhancement bonuses on attack rolls, damage rolls, or both.

Are these enhancement bonuses *magical* enhancement bonuses, suitable for overcoming [DR](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) X/magic, or are these bonuses, as with [masterwork weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#masterworkWeapons), mundane enhancement bonuses?

Such soulmelds include the *bloodtalons* (60), *brass mane* (62-3), *displacer mantle* (64), and *girallon arms* (68). It's this last soulmeld in particular, when bound to his totem chakra, with which my character is particularly concerned. He'd rather have this information in advance instead of gaining such knowledge the hard way in the field, for obvious reasons. (*Hint:* One reason is *He prefers not to die*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soulmelds are magical, so their bonuses are magical, so you get magic enhancement bonuses to attack, to damage, or both, when using certain things, as specified in the soulmeld. It is not necessary for the soulmeld to spell out that it is a magical bonus, any more than it is necessary for [*magic weapon*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicWeapon.htm) to do so.

Note that [overcoming DR/magic officially requires](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction)

> Any weapon with at least a +1 magical enhancement bonus on **attack and damage** rolls

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

, so a bonus to just one of those would be insufficient. In my personal opinion, this is dumb and a magic bonus to either should be sufficient, but RAW is what it is.

As for your totemist's specific items:

- *Girallon Arms* **do** overcome DR

  > Every point of essentia you invest in your girallon arms
  >   grants you a +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls and
  >   damage rolls with your claw attacks.
- *Brass Mane* **does** overcome DR

  > Every point of essentia invested in this
  >   soulmeld grants a +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls and
  >   damage rolls made with the bite attack.
- *Blood Talons* **do not** overcome DR

  > (Totem Bind): Every point of essentia invested in the *bloodtalons* grants
  >   a +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls made with the
  >   claw attacks.
- *Displacer Mantle* **does not** overcome DR

  > Every point of essentia invested in the *displacer mantle*
  >   grants you a +1 enhancement bonus on damage rolls made
  >   with the tentacle attacks.

With thanks to Weaveworker89 for checking the individual soulmelds.